# Why is textmeshpro displaying blurred in game view in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, text, fonts, textmeshpro

For some reason, the textmeshpro text is showing up blurry in the game window in Unity.

Game window, with details of font used in inspector -

[image]

Scene window view -

[image]

I tried increasing the font size and changing the character from dynamic to unicode which did nothing.
I then tried changing the atlas render mode from SDFAA to smooth but then all text disappeared, after a while I just reimported the font and started again but am still having the same problem and unsure of what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

Your [GameView](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html) is pixel-zoomed ... at the top where it says `Scale` you have set `3x`.

> **Scale slider**
> Scroll right to zoom in and examine areas of the Game screen in more detail. This slider lets you zoom out to see the entire screen where the device resolution is higher than the Game view window size. You can also use the scroll wheel and middle mouse button to do this while the application is stopped or paused.

Always keep this at maximum `1` (or below for resolution higher than the GameView window size).

Instead rather make sure your GameView is using the correct target resolution setting